# Retrieve all rows from table except few rows in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 & MySQL as backend to serve REST-API requests made from the mobile app.

I have a **Cart table** and **Items table**. So whenever user comes to *'Items screen'* in his mobile App, In the backend I should perform 2 tasks.

1. First check if any Items are there in his cart. If *yes* (i.e.,there are items in Cart table), then fetch those items from **Cart table** and the remaining items from **Item table**.
2. If there are *no* items in Cart, then I will easily fetch all items from the Items table and show it to user.

I am stuck not being able to perform the task 1. Because I am first retrieving all the *item_ids* from the **Cart table**. It will return a collection. Now I should check if these item_ids(from cart table) are present in **Items table**. If yes, don't fetch those items from **Items table**, BUT fetch all other items from **Items table**. Combine those items from **Items table** & items from **Cart table** and show it to user. How can I achieve this?

Currently, problem is, I am getting all *'item_ids'* from **Cart table**. It returns a collection of item-ids. Using `foreach()` loop, for every *item_id*, I am querying **Items table** as follows:

```
("*where('item_id','!=',$getItemId)->get();*")

$itemDetails = ItemBng::where('store_id','=',$store_id)->where('category_id','=',$category_id)->where('subcategory_id','=',$subcategory_id)->where('item_id','!=',$getItemId)->get();
```

And it returns collection checking against each individual item. and replaces collection with every new iteration in foreach loop.

Here is the function in my **CartController**:

```
public function getItemsWithCartItems($uuid,$store_id,$category_id,$subcategory_id,$subsubcategory_id=null)
{
    try
    {
        $getCartItems = UserCartDetailBng::where('uuid','=',$uuid)->get();
        if($getCartItems->isEmpty()) //Performing task 2. No problem here.
        {
            if($subsubcategory_id==null || $subsubcategory_id==0) // Bcoz, subsubcategory_id is optional
            {
                $itemDetails = ItemBng::where('store_id','=',$store_id)->where('category_id','=',$category_id)->where('subcategory_id','=',$subcategory_id)->get();
                if($itemDetails->isEmpty()){
                    return ResponseService::buildFailureResponse("Store Item not found");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $itemDetails = ItemBng::where('store_id','=',$store_id)->where('category_id','=',$category_id)->where('subcategory_id','=',$subcategory_id)->where('subsubcategory_id','=',$subsubcategory_id)->get();
                if($itemDetails->isEmpty()){
                    return ResponseService::buildFailureResponse("Store Item not found");
                }
            }
            $count = $itemDetails->count();
            $data = array('count'=>$count,'result'=>$itemDetails);
            return ResponseService::buildSuccessResponse($data);
        }
        else  //Performing task 1. Here is the problem.
        {
          // I am using "where('item_id','!=',$getItemId)->get()" And it returns collection checking against each individual item. and replaces collection with every new iteration in foreach loop.
            foreach($getCartItems as $getCartItem)
            {
                $getItemId = $getCartItem->id;
                if($subsubcategory_id==null || $subsubcategory_id==0)
                {
                    $itemDetails = ItemBng::where('store_id','=',$store_id)->where('category_id','=',$category_id)->where('subcategory_id','=',$subcategory_id)->where('item_id','!=',$getItemId)->get();
                    if($itemDetails->isEmpty()){
                        return ResponseService::buildFailureResponse("Store items not found");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $itemDetails = ItemBng::where('store_id','=',$store_id)->where('category_id','=',$category_id)->where('subcategory_id','=',$subcategory_id)->where('subsubcategory_id','=',$subsubcategory_id)->where('item_id','!=',$getItemId)->get();
                    if($itemDetails->isEmpty()){
                        return ResponseService::buildFailureResponse("Store items not found");
                    }
                }
                $count = $itemDetails->count();
                $data = array('count'=>$count,'result'=>$itemDetails);
                return ResponseService::buildSuccessResponse($data);
            }
        }
    }
```

please help me solve this problem, TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your models are set correctly, try this code

```
       //get the cart items with the item
       $cartItems = UserCartDetailBng::where('uuid','=',$uuid)->with('itemsBng')->get();
       if($cartItems->isEmpty())
       {
           //
       }
       else
       {
           //find items excluding of cart items 
           $itemDetails = ItemBng::where('store_id','=',$store_id)
                                   ->where('category_id','=',$category_id)
                                   ->where('subcategory_id','=',$subcategory_id)
                                   ->whereNotIn('id', $cartItems->lists('item_id'))->get();

           $data = array('cartItems'=>$cartItems,'generalItems'=>$itemDetails);
           return ResponseService::buildSuccessResponse($data);
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding the following to your code

Add this after try

```
$getCartItemsIds = UserCartDetailBng::where('uuid','=',$uuid)->lists('id');
```

Remove the foreach block and $getItemId from the else statement then have the $itemdetails retrieved using

```
$itemDetails = ItemBng::where('store_id','=',$store_id)->where('category_id','=',$category_id)->where('subcategory_id','=',$subcategory_id)->whereNotIn($getCartItemsIds)->get();
```

please note you have two different retrievals for $itemDetails edit the second one to also use the `->whereNotIn($getCartItemsIds)`

Lastly as per your intention you should edit the $data returned to include also what is on the cart.

```
$data = array('count'=>$count,'result'=>$itemDetails, 'cart'=>$getCartItems);
```